# jLabel.setVisible(true) doesn't work

Tags: java, jlabel

```
public class Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ArrayList<Integer> numere = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Bila> balls = new ArrayList<Bila>();
ArrayList<String> culori = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<JLabel> colours = new ArrayList<>();
Random random = new Random();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Image");
JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
int nrBalls=0;

public void createColours(){
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        culori.add("Portocaliu");
        culori.add("Rosu");
        culori.add("Albastru");
        culori.add("Verde");
        culori.add("Negru");
        culori.add("Galben");
        culori.add("Violet");
    }
}
public void createNumbers(){
    for(int i=1;i<50;i++){
        numere.add(i);
    }
}
public void createBalls(){
    while(nrBalls<36){
        int indx =random.nextInt(numere.size());
        int nr = numere.get(indx);
        numere.remove(indx);
        String culoare = culori.get(indx);
        culori.remove(indx);
        balls.add(new Bila(culoare,nr));
        nrBalls++;
    }
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    for(int i=0;i<35;i++){
        if(balls.get(i).culoare.equals("Portocaliu")){
            jLabel2.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

} 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
Game game = new Game();
game.createColours();
game.createNumbers();
game.createBalls();
game.afisare();
}  
}
public class Bila {
int nr;
String culoare;
Bila(String culoare,int nr){
    this.nr = nr;
    this.culoare = culoare;
}
```

When I click the button I want it to find in the array the first ball with the respective colour and the `jLabel` to appear. I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException with index:0 size:0`. Does anyone know what is causing this? My array list is not empty, I made a method to print out all the elements in the array and it's not empty. 
stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at turbo6.Game.jButton1MouseClicked(Game.java:154)
    at turbo6.Game.access$100(Game.java:15)
    at turbo6.Game$2.mouseClicked(Game.java:101)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6538)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: method afisare() exists but it's just a debug method to see if it actually puts the the balls in my ArrayList

Comment: Can you please copy paste the exact stack trace?

Comment: i didn't include it in this post becouse it is just a debug method and it is not relevant to my problem

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException ` have nothing to do with `jLabel.setVisible(true) doesn't work`. Please update your tags and title.

Also, why do you add 7 times each color in the array culori?

Are you sure the line of the error is the one with `jLabel2.setVisible(true);`?

Comment: becouse i need 7 time one colour.

Comment: Please stop asking why i did what i did, i need someone to explain me why i get the indexoutofboundsexception

Comment: Change `for(int i=0;i<35;i++){` to `for(int i=0;i<balls.size();i++){`. The error will be gone, but you will have to find out why your ball list is empty

Comment: you actually get that exception because you´re trying to access an index location that is empty. Please provide afisare() as well.

Comment: My guess is you're shadowing your variables

Comment: while(nrBalls<36){ is dangerous because, well, you've found out why, you shouldn't use magic numbers

Comment: the error disappeared when i changed to balls.size().But the label still doesn't appear

Comment: i have 49 numbers and i want it to get 35 random numbers from it and unique.and i create 35 balls with those random numbers and put them in the array..i tried for(int i=0 ;i<35 ;i++){System.out.println(balls.get(i))} and it is working i,overwrite the toString method,and i get in the console 35 unique balls.So the arraylist is not empty

Comment: I also tried for(int i=0;i<balls.size();i++){if(balls.get(i),culoare.equals("Portocaliu")){System.out.println("debug");}}and it is working ..it;s looking in the array and it finds the balls with that colour..but when i try to make the jLabel visible,it just doesn't appear

Comment: @Bai Radule The `balls` list is empty. That is what the exception message says. I suggest you put a `System.out.println("jButton1MouseClicked: balls.size() = " + balls.size());` in the beginning of the `jButton1MouseClicked()` method in order to realize this.

Comment: nevermind guys,i will find it on my own,thanks